# How to make my react app dynamic when fetching api?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, backend

In my react app, im using Im using MySql and NodeJS. When im fetching api, the code looks something like this

```
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/product-from-search', obj)
    .then(function (response) {      
      state.setState({ searchInputResult: response.data })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

how can i make it dynamic so that i only need to write

```
    axios.post('/api/product-from-search', obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your baseURL outside your component and use template literals in your function call.

```
const baseURL = "http://localhost:5000"
~~~
axios.post(`${baseURL}/api/product-from-search`, obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

excuse me if I'm not understanding your question correctly.

I think you are asking how to set your baseURL for Axios, so you can type all your routes as relative instead of absolute ('/api/...' instead of 'http://address:port/api/...')?

You should not need to write the http://localhost:5000 part of the path. Axios should work fine with just just the relative '/api/...'.

If that's NOT the case, I think you might have a CORS issue. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

If you've used create-react-app, then in the package.json (of your react app) add the following line just before the closing curly brace:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

**EDIT: Don't forget to restart your server after doing this!**

If it's a CORS problem, the request is failing because your server is at a different origin (in this case, different port) than your front end, which the browser will block for security reasons.

Of course, you can use AXIOS configuration to set a baseURL so that you don't have to include it in every route as described here: (https://github.com/axios/axios)

```html
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

But I don't think that's your actual issue. Try the proxy in your package.json first.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate 'helper.js' file where you can define a function to configure axios post request as per the requirements.

```js
   
   import React from 'react';

   let baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000";

    export function post(apiEndpoint, payload){
        return  axios.post(baseUrl+apiEndpoint, payload,
        options = { headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Your token goes here',
        }})
        .then((response)=>{
            return response;
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

Now, call this named export into your file with required params.